# Proguard error code 1

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

So, I had this great news when uploading my app on the playstore that every download made gave an error.

Then I found that it could be Proguard.

So, at first my proguard-project was empty and gave 300+ errors, 
Now I added these lines and the proguard-project is exactly like this:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }   
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn javax.activation.**
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-keep class javax.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.** {*;}
-keep public class Mail {*;}        
-dontshrink
```

And gives me the following error:

[2014-10-29 00:50:55 - xxx] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-10-29 00:50:55 - xxx] Error: Can't read [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\rt.jar] (Can't process class [com/oracle/net/Sdp$1.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))
[2014-10-29 00:52:28 - xxx] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-10-29 00:52:28 - xxx] Error: Can't read [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\rt.jar] (Can't process class [com/oracle/net/Sdp$1.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))
[2014-10-29 00:53:50 - xxx] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-10-29 00:53:50 - xxx] Error: Can't read [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\rt.jar] (Can't process class [com/oracle/net/Sdp$1.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))
[2014-10-29 00:54:50 - xxx] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-10-29 00:54:50 - xxx] Error: Can't read [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\rt.jar] (Can't process class [com/oracle/net/Sdp$1.class] (Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))

So I've updated the proGuard and now it gives me this error :

[2014-10-29 01:03:43 - xxx] Error: Can't read [C:\Users\filipe\Desktop\Workspace COMPLETOS\FacebookSDK\bin\facebooksdk.jar] (Can't process class [com/facebook/widget/ProfilePictureView$1.class] (Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream))

This proGuard is driving me insane.

How could I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to add below code to your project's **proguard-project.txt** file.

```
-dontwarn ["error package name or Error file path here"]
```

example as :

```
-dontwarn com.example.media.*
```

and if you have more(insane) errors coming, then just add

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
```

Might be this helpful for you.